# PHP form in HTML, won't connect

Tags: php, database, forms

So I am very new to PHP,and databases in general, so please be indulgent! :)

I created a simple form in an HTML file:

```
<h1> Créez votre compte ici</h1>
<form action="form.php" method="post">
<p id="textdone"> </p>
<input type= "text" name="Surname" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Votre nom" required/> <br> <br>
<input type= "text" name="Name" autocomplete="on" placeholder ="Votre prenom" required/> <br> <br>
<input type= "email" name="Email" autocomplete="on" placeholder ="Adresse mail" required/> <br><br>
<input type= "text" name="Pseudo" autocomplete="off" placeholder ="Votre pseudo" maxlength="20" required/> <br>
<p>Ajoutez une photo de profil: <input type= "file" /> <br><br></p>
<p> Entrez un mot de passe: <input type="Password" name="Passwird" autocomplete="off"  maxlength="20" required placeholder="Mot de passe"/> <br><br>
Validez votre mot de passe: <input type="password1" autocomplete="off"  maxlength="20" required placeholder="Mot de passe"/> <br><br>
    </p>
<input type="submit" value="Soumettre"/>
</form>
    </body>
```

And so my action file, the form.php file, saved in the same folder (I made sure) is as follows:

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'Matchy');
define('DB_USER', 'root@localhost');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link){
    die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected){
    die('Can\'t use' . DB_NAME. ':'. mysql_error());
}
echo 'Successful connection';

$surname = $_POST['Surname'];
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$pseudo = $_POST['Pseudo'];
$password = $_POST['Password'];

$sql = "INPUT INTO users (Name) VALUES ('$name')";
$sql1 = "INPUT INTO users (Surname) VALUES ('$surname')";
$sql2 = "INPUT INTO users (Pseudo) VALUES ('$pseudo')";
$sql3 = "INPUT INTO users (Email) VALUES ('$email')";
$sql4 = "INPUT INTO users (Password) VALUES ('$password')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die ('Error: ' .mysql_error());
}
if (!mysql_query($sql1)) {
    die ('Error: ' .mysql_error());
}
if (!mysql_query($sql2)) {
    die ('Error: ' .mysql_error());
}
if (!mysql_query($sql3)) {
    die ('Error: ' .mysql_error());
}
if (!mysql_query($sql4)) {
    die ('Error: ' .mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

But every time I fill out my form and hit submit, I get this message:
Cannot Post /form.php.

I get this code from this following video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wp6Ngpk5XiY&index=2&list=PL530D33D6E548481F), which was very useful. But I really can't connect. I created my table on my database, with all the right columns.
I use phpMyAdmin.

Thank you so much to anyone who can help!! :)

Comment: Please use mysqli instead of mysql_

Comment: Your file is `form.php` but you have `action="demo.php"` in your form element. Change it to `action="form.php"`.

Comment: Hi, sorry that was a mistake from an old copy/paste, but they are both the same now :) I tried with mysql, still doesn't work :/

Comment: What the error said? `root@localhost` is the user you created? i believe default user is `root` without @localhost

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I just changed that, doesn't change anything :/

Comment: In my console I don't get any error. And in phpMyAdmin they give me this username. I also tried with root, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: If you navigate to your domain that hosts the file does `/form.php` call your PHP code? perhaps you haven't specified the full URI for the location of form.php ?

Comment: Is `INPUT` a valid mysql command? Shouldn't it be `INSERT INTO users (Name) VALUES ('$name');` instead? Maybe that is just a mysql thing I am not familiar with.

Comment: `INPUT INTO users (Name) VALUES ('$name')` not `INSERT INTO users (Name) VALUES ('$name')` ?

Comment: Just tried INSERT, doesn't work :/

Comment: I tried with the full file name, with a full path. Doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Where does the error you are getting: "Cannot Post /form.php" get generated from? I don't see that in your code above.

Comment: *ahem* `name="Passwird"` and `$_POST['Password']` = *no love*. and this http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have told you about it.

Comment: I get it from here: http://127.0.0.1:54886/form.php

Comment: I mean, that message should be in your code somewhere. Where is the line of code that prints that message at?

Comment: Is the form.php inside folder were 127.0.0.1:54886 is pointing to?

Comment: @gmiley, that code is nowhere in my code. I don't understand it either.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hat off :D `<input type="password1" autocomplete="off"  maxlength="20" required placeholder="Mot de passe"/>` this one is providing no love too. No input`type` password1

Comment: @DavidLavieri actually I'm not sure how to check that!

Comment: sure like to know where you got this syntax from though `INPUT INTO`.

Comment: @HendraNucleo ah good catch on that ;-) yeah, OP's code contains a LOT of syntax errors and error reporting would have definitely been their best friend today ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks! I just changed it!

Comment: @HendraNucleo Thanks as well, modified that.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I got the code from the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wp6Ngpk5XiY&index=2&list=PL530D33D6E548481F)

Comment: @AndreDebuisne you will need to do some more analysis then. My suggestion would be to map out all the files that are referenced in your page, and any files they include or reference. You would probably then want to add some `echo`s that print out some identifying information so you can track down where  the general area is that your code is failing.

Comment: @AndreDebuisne well that video needs to be taken down *lol*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think it's outdated, I probably should use a new one!

Comment: @gmiley I will do that. Thank you so much for your time! :)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think I need to start off with a new tutorial!

Comment: @AndreDebuisne Best to use the right references http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html and switch to [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) or [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. The official manuals are the best references. ;-)

Comment: Sure, if you can narrow it down more, update your question and we can probably give you a little more solid help. At this point, it is a little too unclear as to what your actual problem is unfortunately.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thank you for all the great references! Will check it out tonight, hopefully my form will be functional by tonight! :)

Comment: @gmiley yes I think the problem here is I need to use mysqli!

Comment: @AndreDebuisne You're welcome Andre.

Comment: @AndreDebuisne I made a few more edits to my answer that you may be interested (and should be) reading. A few things that that tutorial may not have covered, so please reload it to see the changes made.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Just saw that, thank you! I'm on it right now!

Comment: 32 comments and 1 vote up. Simple question surrounded by nice people's :D

Comment: @HendraNucleo I know, it's amazing! Amazing community!

Comment: @AndreDebuisne So how its going then ? any luck ?

Comment: @HendraNucleo   I realized the problem relies in the link between the form.php and my html file. I think it's a problem with the path, I can't find the proper one to put in action="../../form.php"

Comment: @AndreDebuisne form.php is within same folder right ?

Comment: @Yes it is, I double/triple checked. I tried with a simple php, with a simple echo, but I still get the same message...

Comment: @AndreDebuisne Load comment under Fred-ii answer below and join chat room (click the link). I will give short guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's outline the errors here.

`INPUT INTO` isn't a valid MySQL expression, the syntax is `INSERT INTO`.

Then you have `name="Passwird"` and `$_POST['Password']` which do not match and error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have told you about it.

Then as outlined in comments by another member:

> *`<input type="password1" autocomplete="off" maxlength="20" required placeholder="Mot de passe"/>` this one is providing no love too. No inputtype password1 – Hendra Nucleo*

which should have been `password` and not `password1`.

Best to use the right and official references http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html and switch to [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) or [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. The official manuals are the best references.

- They won't steer you wrong ;-)

That tutorial probably didn't mention anything about [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/), so that's a good read in its own right.

Nor did it mention anything about passwords.

I noticed that you may be storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

**Important sidenote about column length:**

If and when you do decide to use `password_hash()` or the compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/, it is important to note that if your present password column's length is anything lower than 60, it will need to be changed to that (or higher). The manual suggests a length of 255.

You will need to ALTER your column's length and start over with a new hash in order for it to take effect. Otherwise, MySQL will fail silently.

---

**Edit:**

That whole block of code could have easily been done in a few lines, such as and without so many calls to the same table:

```
$sql = mysql_query("

        INSERT INTO users (Name, Surname, Pseudo, Email, Password) 
        VALUES ('$name', '$surname', '$pseudo', '$email', '$password')

        ");

if($sql){
echo "Success!";
}

else { "Error: " . mysql_error(); }
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- Simple question, why is no error when using procedural approach for open connection and select database, then using `$var->query('SELECT * FROM table_name') for running query?

Comment: This is definitely a much better answer than the other and covers several good points. This is a good place to start from. A good take-away from this would be: Try to do as much analysis and planning up-front, especially when it comes to your database design and the technology (language, code structure, framework, and libraries). Even though it appears you are just trying to learn a lot of this, it is best to get into good habits early. It will minimize problems and make it easier for others to help you when one does creep up.

Comment: @HendraNucleo The particular error may very well be occurring much earlier in the code execution than that particular call.

Comment: @gmiley Absolutely no error mate, successfull query with data pulled from database.

Comment: @HendraNucleo If no error checking is used in either procedural or object oriented, then it won't throw anything unless the server itself is already setup to throw them without having to use error checking functions. This I mean at the sysop level on a * NIX system that is and most of us those have that high an access level.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Error checking exist with error thrown if persist. Is `$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password);` threated similar to `$con = new mysqli()` ?

Comment: @HendraNucleo However, certain things can and will fail silently in MySQL. One of them being for column lengths. If for example a password column is too short to accommodate a hash that is 60 chars. long and the column is 50, then that's a silent fail. There are other scenarios though, but would be too long a discussion at this point ;-)

Comment: @HendraNucleo Both are similar, yet some like to use one method over another; it's a personal preference really. I use both myself, not always the same one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I remember a quote 'Teaching is not in my DNA' so lets moving & sneaking into Q by Q :D `def: cheers` `python import beer` `composer init --party` :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110031/discussion-between-hendra-nucleo-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, @gmiley raised a good question, check whether you can use input or not and instead use insert query with all the values in single statement. For syntax, you can refer the following link:http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: well guy smiley didn't pick up on something else and that isn't my downvote you see there ;-)

Comment: I didn't get you, wat are u trying to say

Comment: This isn't really an answer, more of a comment.

Comment: Okay, I'll take care from next time. Thanks